# Batch converting PNG images to JPG using ImageMagick's Mogrify

Tags: linux, command-line, imagemagick

I need to batch convert PNG files to JPG at a quality of 90% but also keep the resolution at 72dpi. I came up with this command:

```
mogrify -format jpg -quality 90 -density 72x72 *.png
```

or should I use?:

```
mogrify -format jpg -quality 90 -units PixelsPerInch -density 72 *.png
```

Do you think it is okay? Did I miss any parameter that would be useful? I would like to keep the color profile and EXIF information of the PNGs as well.

Comment: 72 dpi is not a resolution, it is at best merely a suggestion of display size once printed. dpi has no bearing on an image before printing. Imges have dimensions in pixels, nothing else.